# protect_from_forgery how to handle resulting exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, controller

When using `protect_from_forgery with: :exception` in a Web App, how it is possible not to expose the exception to the user.

Let's say that when this exception is raised I would like to refresh the current page and push a flash message on top of the screen (I already have mechanisms to handle the flash messages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  add following method

```
def handle_unverified_request
    render status: 422, template: 'errors/unacceptable'
  end
```

in your application_controller, and do your error handling there